# coffee "Elite" from Israel

Tags: cooking-bishul

In the newspaper "Hapeles" published in Israel, an ad published in the name of Rabbi Mordechai Gross shlit'a says that there is a problem with the coffee produced by "Elite" Israel . It is forbidden to use it regularly on Shabbat; it needs to be made only in a "Kli Shlishi".

I use this cafe, do you know what happened?

[image: The ad warning about the coffee.]

Comment: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/38180/whats-wrong-with-making-coffee-on-shabbat

Comment: I also drink this. But possibly it was discovered that the coffee grinds (that were turned into instant coffee) doesn't go through a full process of "bishul" so therefore it would be mevashel in a kli sheini as it would be considered kalei habishul

Comment: Is it possible to ask "Elite" If there is any change in the manufacturing process.
I would be grateful to those who can do it.

Answer (score 3):

If I had to venture a guess? People had probably assumed it was entirely freeze-dried coffee -- i.e. cook the coffee, then take out all the water.

[Forbes notes](http://fortune.com/2009/10/02/starbucks-new-high-tech-coffee/):

> [Starbucks] Via is a combination of dried coffee and “micro-ground” coffee.

So if other brands contain micro-grounds, those [presumably] haven't yet been cooked. Which would necessitate a *kli shlishi*.

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/14308/starbucks-via-on-shabbat I really doubt Elite coffee is anything but spray dried. Even if, though, micro-ground is not uncooked.

Answer (score 2):

Concurring with Shalom's answer, and based on experience, I believe Elite has always been microground.  I believe this is not a change, and I know many people have used a Keli Shelishi for it (and other coffees, incidentally).

Comment: I also don't believe the warning is new, but I may be mistaken about that.

Comment: Elite doesn't leave grinds at the bottom of the cup (a tell-tale sign of micro-grinding, AFAIK). It is a thin powder because it is spray dried. Besides, as Shalom linked, Micro-grinding is a new invention. Elite has been ruining morning coffee in Yeshiva for decades.

Comment: @Yishai, I stand by my answer. I think it may even say on the package that it is micro ground.